# Sugarcrm file upload

Tags: php, module, sugarcrm

I am fairly new to sugarcrm and php as well. I want to create a custom module to upload files to sugarcrm database as blob. So far I have created a custom module using the module builder. It is a file type so it allows to upload the file, but only the file name is saved in the database. I want to save the file contents as a blob. Is there a way to do this. Please let me know

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will attempt to help, but I need a little more information on what exactly you are looking to upload.  Is it an image file or a document?  There are built in handlers for both, so you might be going about it the hard way depending on your need.

If you are uploading an image, there is a field type that handles uploading images, and storing them in the cache area (this is the default storage location).

If you are needing to upload documents, there are default handlers built into most of the existing modules (Contacts, Leads, and Accounts all have it).  I would recommend snooping around in that code, since most of the hard work will most likely be done.

+++ Ok, I didn't realize that you were specifically looking to store in blob only.  Just an FYI, it's not going to be advisable to store this data in the standard _cstm table, since the bean class will attempt to load this data into an object EVERY time you make a call to that particular module, which will put a huge drain on server resources.  You will want to separate the table in a standard 3NF fashion.

With that said, you will need to create a binary-conversion class/method (do a quick search to see some prefabbed ones).  Assuming that you are using the proper field type (File, and note a text field), you will want to create a new handler file for the save action, set it as an entry point.

The file should look something like:

```
<?php
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

require_once('include/formbase.php');
require_once('modules/[MODULE TYPE]/config.php');
require_once('include/SugarFields/SugarFieldHandler.php');

$focus = new [MODULE TYPE]();
$focus = populateFromPost('', $focus);

if(!$focus->ACLAccess('Save')){
    ACLController::displayNoAccess(true);
    sugar_cleanup(true);
}

//SOME CODE TO CONVERT TO BINARY AND THEN STORE VALUE INTO FIELD NAME USING
// $focus->[fieldName] = outputFromBinaryConversion($_POST['theFileField']);
// That would store the blob into the existing _cstm table
// --OR, you would get the id of the saved module using $return_id = $focus->id;
// and use the id to link to the blob stored in another (unsupported) table.


$focus->save();
```

I hope that clarifies your direction a bit, but I would really recommend looking at using the existing document handling class, as it will be much cleaner and quicker to implement.

Comment: Hi,Thank you so much for the reply. I want to upload documents. Yes they are already handlers for it, but they just save the document in the folder. I want to save the file contents as a blob in the database.I want to create a field blob in the database and add the file contents to it automatically when the user submits the document.